# How to give a developer access to my Google App Engine project?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've got a Google App Engine project account and want to give access to a new developer who's going to help out, but I don't want him to have the account access details. How do I add him as a user so he can deploy and test code on my account (locally on his machine using the SDK and live), but not do anything I don't want him to do with the account?

I know I need to use IAM roles somehow, but does the developer already need a Google account (don't think he has one) or can I just send an invite to his existing email etc?

Many thanks,
Alex

Comment: Visit https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/add-remove-change-permissions-for-team-members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your developer will require a Google account, which can be a gmail account or a Google Apps account.

Check out the [description of the App Engine IAM](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/access-control) roles and then [grant the appropriate access](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/granting-project-access) to your developer's Google account.

In your case that might be either "Editor" or "App Engine Service Admin".